# C# Datagridview - Check Row is Selected

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have this code in my C# program, but it throws a fit when some buttons are clicked because there is no row selected in the DataGridView (I use the ClearSelection method):

```
string selectedUser = usersGrid.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
```

Is there some sort of check I can do before the above line to ensure that a row is selected?

Comment: I thought my post was clear enough, and the guys below got exactly what was wrong.  Sorry for any confusion.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
if (usersGrid.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
```

Answer (score 7):

I am going to take a stab at what I think you are trying to do, try this below

```
private void myButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in usersGrid.Rows)
    {
        if (this.usersGrid.SelectedRows.Count == 1)
        {
         // get information of 1st column from the row
         string selectedUser = this.usersGrid.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

also do the following as well and checkout the link

Set [DataGridView.MultiSelect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.multiselect.aspx)=false and [DataGridView.SelectionMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectionmode.aspx) = FullRowSelect.  This will make it so the user can only select a single row at a time.

Comment: This works too, but I prefer the > 0 which Tergiver mentioned :)